# jvisualvm do not monitor local JBoss application on Windows 7 / Windows 2008

Tags: jboss, jvisualvm

When I start JVisualVM on Windows 7 or Windows 2008 there is no way to find JBoss instances running on the same machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the JBoss command line using the "Run as administrator" feature of Windows 7 or Windows 2008.

This probably could solve also problems in other profilers for the Java VM when you run them in the same operating systems.